# requestFocus() giving null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I have an edit text in my activity and want to request focus on it. However, it always crashes upon launching the activity.

Java code:

```
foodText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.foodName);
prepText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.prepText);
foodText.requestFocus();
```

Activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_add_food"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.rcadit.foodgenie.AddFood">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
style="@style/AppTheme"
        >


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:transitionName="addFood">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/foodName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Food name"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
android:inputType="textCapWords"
android:textColor="@color/colorIcons"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorIcons"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"

            android:textSize="16sp"

            android:text="Hunger Level" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/hunger_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:padding="16dp"

            >

        </Spinner>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Cuisine" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/cuisine_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:padding="16dp"

            >

        </Spinner>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Preparation Time" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/prepText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="Enter Preparation Time"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Course" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/course_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:padding="16dp"

            >

        </Spinner>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Salty"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/howSalty"
            android:hint="Salty"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/salty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:thumbTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:progressTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:max="2"
            android:progress="1"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sweet"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/howSweet"
            android:hint="Sweet"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <SeekBar
            android:thumbTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:progressTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:id="@+id/sweet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="2"
            android:progress="1"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Spicy"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/howSpicy"
            android:hint="Spicy"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />
        <SeekBar
            android:thumbTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:progressTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:id="@+id/spicy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="2"
            android:progress="1"

            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Special Requirements"

            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="3">



            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dairyFree"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dairy Free"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/nutFree"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nut Free"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/eggFree"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Egg Free"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/vegetarian"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vegetarian"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
        </GridLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:onClick="add"

            android:text="Add" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have looked at other questions but I can't see why my code doesn't work as the ID's are correct and I can't find the fault in the code.

Log file:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.rcadit.foodgenie, PID: 3221
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rcadit.foodgenie/com.example.rcadit.foodgenie.AddFood}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.EditText.requestFocus()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.EditText.requestFocus()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.rcadit.foodgenie.AddFood.onCreate(AddFood.java:60)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3221 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: post your full code where you call the method..

Comment: Indeed we need to know where these three lines are located "foodText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.foodName);
prepText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.prepText);
foodText.requestFocus();"

Comment: Try writing it in the layout itself.

Comment: also it's best advised to not have any capitalizations in Id and res in android... it tends to cause issues

Comment: check correct xml file in setcontentview

Comment: check configchanges of this activity in manifest

Comment: I bet wether you are initializing the views before `setContentView()` or you are referencing a wrong layout in `setContentView()`

Comment: i initialized the views before setContentView() :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to reproduce your error by not calling setContentView() before using your code. 
So the correct way to do it is to do:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
        foodText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.foodName);
        prepText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.prepText);
        foodText.requestFocus();
}
```

`your_activity` is basically the name of your `xml` file without the `xml` extension.
For more documentation on Views you can check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int) or this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) ifwhat you're doing is creating a second Activity. (both refer to the official documentation and give examples and explanations)

Also I suppose that you would get the same error if you don't use the right name of file for the `setContentView()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried at my end its working fine with exact your params.

[image]

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        EditText number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.foodName);
        number.requestFocus();

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/foodName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:hint="Food name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you call `findViewById()` method before `setContentView()` method.